# HTML/CSS How to align these items horizontally?

Tags: html, css

In my view I am trying to align the following horizontally (so there would be the checkbox then the bar and rest all on one line):

[image: ??]

In my view:

```
 <div class="tableHomework2">
            <%= link_to homework do %>
              <div class="teachers linkable">
                    <%= check_box_tag "homework[id][]", homework.id, checked = false, class: "narrowtr" %>
                    <div class="progress-meter-interest-mobile horizTranslate" data-bar-length=" <%= homework.average_interest * 100 / 5 %>%"><%= homework.average_interest %></div>
                    <font size="1"><%= homework.significance.sig_option %></font>&emsp;&ensp;
                    <font size="1"><strong><%= formatted_date(homework.due)%></strong></font>
                </div>
                <% end %>
                <% end %>
                <% end %>
```

My Divs in CSS:

```
.teachers {
   border-bottom: 20px;
   background-color: white;
   top: 0px;
   margin:0px;  
   padding: 0px 2px 2px 3px;    
   border-width: 2px;
   border-bottom-width:1px;
   border-bottom-color:Grey;
   border-bottom-style: solid;
   width: 100%;
}

.linkable{
    color: black
}

.progress-meter-interest-mobile{
  background-color: #FFD733;
  width: 10px;
  height: 20px;
}

.progress-meter-interest-mobile.horizTranslate {
  -webkit-transition: 3s;
  -moz-transition: 3s;
  -ms-transition: 3s;
  -o-transition: 3s;
  transition: 3s;
}
```

If I take out the CSS bar from the view it aligns vertically nicely. With the bar it appears as in the image. I'm wondering how can this be done with that div for the bar included? I tried setting max-width in that div but this did not work.

Any suggestions? Thanks.

RE: checkbox

Page source

```
<div class="show-for-small-only">
          <div class="tableHomework2">
            <a href="/homeworks/76">
              <div class="teachers linkable">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="homework[id][]" id="homework_id_" value="76" class="narrowtr" />
                    <div class="progress-meter-interest-mobile horizTranslate" data-bar-length=" 60%">3</div>
                    <font size="1">High</font>&emsp;&ensp;
                    <font size="1"><strong>25/11/2016</strong></font>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is the [`display`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display) property. You can use it like:

```
.example {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! :) Worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

can be implemented like this:

```
.teachers .progress-meter-interest-mobile, .teachers input[type="checkbox"]{
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:top
}
```

Comment: Thanks!, the other problem I have incidentally you may have guessed is the checkbox does not work because the div is a link. :( Do you know is there a workaround for this? Thanks.

Comment: Can you please provide here output of the given source code? (without source code)

Comment: Not sure exactly what you mean but I printed page source on relevant div in OP?...is that helpful at all?

Comment: ah. I got <input tag is inside <a> tag. this is not good, please remove that. and let us know why you need this <a> tag

Comment: Thanks, I took out of <a> tag and works nice now. I just needed it so user can go to view record by clicking on div :) Thanks for help! Much appreciate it.